# Creating a manuscript like table output from the multiple variables' frequency and proportions outcome

Tags: r, rbind, cbind

I have been wondering is it possible to create a table (i.e. tables usually used in the manuscript) from the multiple variables' frequencies and proportions values.

I have been experimenting this with this dataset and codes:

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars)

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1

attach(mtcars)
```

Now I am creating some tables using the categorical variables of this dataset. At first, I am using `am` variable of `mtcars` dataset.

```
t1 = table (am)
t1

am
0   1
19  13

p1 = round(prop.table(t1),3)*100
p1

am
   0     1
59.4  40.6
```

Similarly I am creating some tables with frequencies and proportions with the other variables i.e. `vs`, `gear` `carb`.
Followings are the codes:

```
t2 = table(vs)
t2
p2 = round(prop.table(t2),3)*100
p2

t3 = table(gear)
t3
p3 = round(prop.table(t3),3)*100
p3

t4 = table(carb)
t4
p4 = round(prop.table(t4),3)*100
p4
```

**Now I want to create a table like output from R, like this picture:**

[image]

**The actual outcome with the values from the above-mentioned codes by me is here in this picture:**

[image]

I have tried with the `rbind()` and `cbind()` function. But could not be able to manage the right codes.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/finalfit/vignettes/all_tables_examples.html

Comment: @user63230

Thanks for mentioning this packages. It would be very handy if I ever try to analyze the 2x2 tables. 

But, I could not find any codes, from which I could create my desired table (mentioned above in the picture of my question). I am not an expert in the R world. Could you guide me through it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using additional packages, you could check out `summarytools` (https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools).

Here is an example (is usually renders as html, but I saved a PNG image for demonstration purposes):

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(invisible(
    lapply(c("summarytools", "dplyr", "kableExtra"),
           require, character.only = TRUE)))
dfs <- dfSummary(mtcars[, c("am", "vs", "gear", "carb")], 
  round.digits = 3,
  varnumbers = FALSE,
  valid.col = FALSE, 
  na.col = FALSE, 
  graph.col = FALSE,
  style = "grid",
  tmp.img.dir = "/tmp",
  method = "grid") %>% 
  mutate(`Stats / Values` = NULL) #%>% view() to view the html output
print(dfs, method = 'render') %>% as_image(file="out1.png")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit**

If you insist on building your own tables (and possibly exporting them to Word), there is one issue with your proposed table: In R, columns can only have one class, so you would have to coerce at least the 'variable' column to characters. That will also affect the alignment and will not look as pretty.

There is also one issue with `rbind` - the column names have to match.

While there are several ways how you can work around these issues, it may be easier to take a different approach.

There are several packages that allow you to generate html tables, such as `flextable`, `huxtable`, `kableExtra`, but AFAIK, you will have to combine them afterwards, e.g. by using Rmarkdown or copying them one by one and pasting them into Word, which will maintain the formatting.

Below is one possible approach, using Rmarkdown. You would have to save the code below as a Rmd file, and knit it, which is easy to to in Rstudio (just open the Rmd file and press the `knit` button).
This will generate a html file in the same directory as the Rmd file, which contains your tables.

````
---
  output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(invisible(
  lapply(c("dplyr", "knitr", "kableExtra"),
         require, character.only = TRUE)))

makeTable <- function(x, df=mtcars){
  df %>%
    count(!!enquo(x)) %>%
    mutate(prop = scales::percent(prop.table(n/n()), accuracy = .01))
}

# generate the individual data.frames
res <- list(makeTable(am), 
            makeTable(vs),
            makeTable(gear), 
            makeTable(carb))

for (i in res) {
  print(kable_styling(
    kable(i, format = "html", align = "c", row.names = FALSE), 
    full_width = FALSE))
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But could you please tell me how could I get this same output as yours by using the  following function-

t1 = table()

Comment: I have tried to convert these table: t1, t2, t3 and t4 into data frame by using `as.data.frame()` function. Still I am getting the error. Following is the error message:


`Error in [.data.frame(mtcars, , c("dt1", "dt2", "dt3", "dt4")) : 
  undefined columns selected`